# Getting a question closed due to wrong assumptions

Tags: support, specific-question

I'm not sure how to phrase the issue without sounding annoyed (and annoyed I am big time, haha) so please poke me if I'm unclear on something.

I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25143466/regex-not-matching-certain-fragments-of-a-string) after I've done some searching. It contained what I've done this far and both the expected and actual sample. The question got closed as a dupe.

I've read several times through the alleged duplicate and I realize that the voters for closing **think** that it's a dupe based on a (totally incorrect) assumption of what I'm asking. Given that assumption, the closing is correct. However, the assumption is way off and the closing unnecessary.

I reposted the question making it very clear what's **not** intended. My impression is that people don't bother to read the text because one user asked why I reposed it again (it's in the first paragraph to see!). Someone else asked politely for a sample. But that's in the question too!

I'm assuming that I'm unclear or something but I see no way to improve my clarity without being obnoxious and fighty. Any hints on how to circumfere readers' pre-suppositions in a polite way?

Comment: The dupe is deleted (not visible <10K)

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion Weird. The "dupe" **is** visible. But it's not marked as a dupe. It was closed before. It's not now. I don't understand...

Comment: @KonradViltersten, it was [reopened](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/25143466/revisions).

Comment: @gunr2171 Oh, I didn't see any notification on that and assumed that it was a lost cause not worth fighting (almost). As I said before - SO grumpy today.   :)

Comment: Looks like a repost to me.  Happens alot--users post (bad) questions, then post a new one that's barely different.  A cursory examination of both would lead anybody to assume that's what you did.  In fact, without reading through them both (lol, didn't read) I'm left wondering how this isn't what you did...

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194476/someone-flagged-my-question-as-already-answered-but-its-not

Comment: @Will Actually, that **is** what I did. The original question wasn't bad nor dupe. After asking a guy how to make it more clear and elaborative, I followed his hint and posted (almost) the same (good and unique) contents with a very clear disclaimer. My question **here** on Meta is how to handle situations when people don't read the actual question, presume a lot of incorrect things and then close the question. Reposting hoping for the viewers to actually read seems to be the only option. Iäm open for different suggestions...

Comment: @gnat Thanks, that's great. It's just that I wished for feedback on how to improve my particular question. Also, the reasoning assumes that the said post is flawed (which might be the case many times). It's kind of depressing when bundled with lousy questions based on the fact that people don't put effort into trying to understand. I've seen that quite many times this year - people are jumping to conclusions based on the general suspicion of lousiness. Degrading to both parties...   :)

Comment: You've confused the hell out of me.  Your question sounds completely different than what you now say happened.  There's no mention in the question that you asked a dupe of your own question rather than just edit the original.  I don't know why you didn't edit the original.  I don't know why I care.  Wait, I don't.  I'm going to go soak my sore head now.  Thanks for befuddling me.

Comment: @Will Sorry if I was unclear. In fact, I followed the suggestion given by the site (telling me to rephrase and ask again). Was that incorrect? I'm trying to follow the rules and suggestions but it seems like I'm being misinterpreted... Feeling a bit like a newbie, hehe.

Answer (score 9):

If people are making assumptions about your question then it's likely that you've not included enough information in the question. You need to make your questions crystal clear.

What you should have done is edit your original question to make it clear and understandable and it would have been added to the reopen review queue where it can be reopened - should 5 other users agree.

If your original question is unsalvageable then delete it *before* posting the new version otherwise people are quite likely to close it as a duplicate.

Comment: I'm more looking for a hint on how to be more clear in **this particular** case. It's easier for me (a single user) to be more clear than for the rest (a lots of lots of users) to put in more effort. Having agreed on that point, I still can't see how to be more crystal in my crystal clarity. Hints are welcome. :)

Comment: In addition, don't talk about the _question_ itself in the question. Long meta intros are distracting and usually unclear. It's way more helpful (and less likely to cause a grumpy reaction) if you talk about how the _problem_ is different.

Comment: @JoshCaswell When I posted a very neutral question another time, the first wave of response was agitating "*what question, where is the question*". Too little info - post error log! Too much text, skip the log! Explain what you did! You didn't say what you've tried! It's too general! It's too specific! If one actually cares to read my question, one can see that I tagged it as "support" and am asking on how to improve **this** particular question. So, no. I **should** be talking about that question. I suspect that you think I'm just whining, which I'm not. Just tired of users jumping to concl.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear myself, @KonradViltersten, but I meant talking about your Stack Overflow question in that question, not in this Meta question. Talking about an SO question in a Meta question is of course perfectly okay.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Got it. Will keep it in mind for the future. This got all too complicated, hehe. While I admit that the major portion of the responsibility for the cooperation on SO falls on the OP (in this case - me), I feel that there are limits to how much one can be expected to clarify one's question. How can one **emphasise and stress** that the readers should take a chill pill before lamenting about dupes and such **still being polite and considerate**? I'm not sure how to handle such situations... The general hints are not specific enough as they address slightly different issue.